# std:: namespace needs to be specified for one type but not another in the cpp file

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a line of code in my C++ file as such:

```
  vector<pair<vector<Block>, vector<string>>> groupedRequests;
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
error: no template named 'pair'; did you mean 'std::pair'?
  vector<pair<vector<Block>, vector<string>>> groupedRequests;
         ^~~~
         std::pair
third-party-buck/gcc-5-glibc-2.23/build/boost/5c6f7a9/include/boost/container/detail/std_fwd.hpp:36:8: note: 'std::pair' declared here
struct pair;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I am not using the namespace std in my class, however it is likely being used in one of the header files I include.  What I don't get is why it requires std::pair, but not std::vector.  If I change to std::pair or specify using namespace std, the code compiles and runs just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: [I can't reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85592c989b5455db) We need a [mcve], preferrably with a link to https://gcc.godbolt.org/ . Also, are you sure you don't have `using std::vector;` somewhere?

Comment: When you use `std::pair`, does it then compile? Or does it then complain about vector? Though, I guess if it parsed vector first, maybe not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, that's probably the case.  I depend on several different header files which then depend on other header files.  One of them is possibly doing that then.  I thought you had to specify a namespace with 'using'; didn't realize you can use it with a specific type.  Thanks!

Comment: @PhilM Yes, compiles and runs just fine if I use std::pair.  HolyBlackCat's answer makes sense and is the likely cause.

Comment: There could also be a global `class vector` defined in some header file that does not necessarily have anything to do with `std::vector`...

Comment: It's not really clear what question you're asking. Is your question "Why does one work and not the other?". If so, which one do you think is working?

Comment: Another possibility might be that `using namespace std;` happened but the header for `pair` isn't included, and the code that generates the error messages is naive

Comment: You can use the `-E` option of the compiler to only preprocess the code. You could use the result to determine if there is some declaration making `vector` work without qualification (most likely a `using` declaration or a `using` alias). It is a while since I have verified but at some point all compilers I had access to supported the `-E` option (although I think MSVC++’s `cl` spelled it `/E`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible explanations are -

1. There is a `using std::vector` somewhere in a header
2. There is a `#define vector std::vector` somewhere in a header

Obviously without seeing all the headers not really a way to tell if either of those are causing it, but either one can replicate the behavior described, i.e.

```
#include <vector>
#define vector std::vector

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
}
```

compiles, where

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

#define vector std::vector

int main() {
  vector<pair<int, int>> v;
}
```

does not unless `std::pair` is specified, same goes for replacing `#define vector std::vector` with `using std::vector;`

Comment: Could also have `typedef std::vector vector;` somewhere, or perhaps even `class vector : public std::vector {`...

Comment: @ChrisDodd I can't get `class vector : public std::vector {`... to compile, even specifying `std::vector<int>` won't compile with the error *'vector' is not a template*. I suppose it would need to be declared as a template in order to be used how the question does? Or I've done something wrong... also `typedef std::vector vector` similarly fails to compile - *invalid use of template-name* `'std::vector'` *without an argument list*

Comment: Yes, it would need to be a template to work as a template.  My point is that there are many ways you could write something that results in this error

Comment: A templated using could indeed still work, the typedef only works without template arguments